# How SSDP over HTTP works?

Tags: http, upnp

```
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
MAN: "ssdp:discover "
MX: 1
ST: urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1
```

this is a request message of SSDP for discovering service on LAN that use Multicasting .
But what is http/1.1 doing here? if it use http what is its method? what it means it is a M-SEARCH message in http?

Answer (score 1):

Read about the
[Simple Service Discovery Protocol (SSDP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol).

SSDP messages conform to the header field format of HTTP 1.1.
It's important to note that SSDP does not allow any message to contain a body;
everything is shared via those header fields.

These are UPnP discovery packets. Their purpose is to discover UPnP devices like
home routers or media servers. If UPnP is enabled in your router,
the software that wants to find it can add port mappings, delete port mappings,
get the external IP address (the router IP), etc.

SSDP can also be used in
[DDOS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack).
See for example
[Stupidly Simple DDoS Protocol (SSDP) generates 100 Gbps DDoS](https://blog.cloudflare.com/ssdp-100gbps/).